# OR operator in .where AngularFire

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I want to get data from firebase .where() 
for example:
get data from database with attributes type = 'shirt' and type = 'pants'
So, essentially an OR operator in a .where function in AngularFire Firestore

Similar to '||' in a JavaScript IF statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether a specific field in your documents has one of multiple values, you can use the [`in` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) of Firestore.

So something like:

```
where('type', 'in', ['shirt', 'pants'])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use where operator as follows.
this.firestore
.collection(orgId)
.doc('VEHICLES')
.collection('LOCATION_CHANGES', ref => ref.where('containerId', '==',
containerId).limit(1));